# Error running Python script from shell

Tags: python, terminal

I am trying to pipe output from a command written in the terminal to a Python script.

For example:

```
ls | ./foo.py
```

I wrote a Python script to do the same:

```
#foo.py
import fileinput

with fileinput.input() as f_input : 
    for line in f_input : 
        print(line,end='')
```

But this does not seem to work,
when I run the following command:

```
$ ls | sudo ./foo.py
```

I get an error that says:

```
$ ./foo.py: command not found
```

I have checked the working directory and I can see the `foo.py` when I use the `ls` command, so what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you forgot the [**Shebang**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import fileinput

with fileinput.input() as f_input :
    for line in f_input :
        print(line,end='')
```

Also remember make it as executable via command:

```
chmod +x foo.py
```

Then run your command again.

Comment: @ironstein: `env` is a command, it can auto search the `PATH` and run `python3`. And then since it's Shebang, the system will use `python3` run your script instead of `bash`.  Try `env --help` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pipe it to the Python executable, not to the name of a file. As the error says, that filename doesn't represent a command it knows.

```
ls | py ./foo.py
```

Use `py` or `python` or however you run the Python interpreter on your particular system.